# Conversations with vulgar words

Tags: family, halal-haram

I have some relatives and we talk nearly every single day. And they keep cursing while i keep saying not to do it. (They already know it is forbidden) I keep telling them to shut their mouth, but now that i think about it, it's kinda harsh, would like to know if it’s REALLY okay to say that.

Anyways, can i still talk to them even if they continue swearing and am i obliged to keep telling them to not do it every single time they do?

Answer (score -1):

You did your job

According to experts the real formula to insist someone is

> Non continuously insist

just like advertisements they offer you something but not all the time they offer you in Non continuous way.

And

--> You can still talk to him ultimately you are the one who can make him right and remember don't swearing while talk to him.

--> if he affects you then you should leave him.